# Ruby On Rails One-One relationship On Same Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I have a table with the following columns (table name categories)

- id
- title
- summary
- parent_id

How do I setup the relationship so I can do something like @category.parent.title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => :parent_id
has_many :categories, :foreign_key => :parent_id
```

Note that if a category has no parent category and you try to access it anyway, you get an error.

Comment: Why do I need the has_many categories when a category can only have 1 parent?

Comment: One category has many subcategories. That's why. `belongs_to` is to access the parent, `has_many` is to access the children.

Answer (score 0):

Use the acts_as_tree gem?

More info [here](https://github.com/parasew/acts_as_tree).